# How to loop a file check until conditions are met in Visual studio 2017 with vb code?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to loop a file check until 1 file is there and the file that creates that file is gone. I keep trying to rewrite and have been trying to find a working setup but just can't find any this is the code that I have currently

```
Dim dir = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 25 Then
        Do
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                If FileExists(dir + "\download\downloaded.mp3") Then
                    If FileExists(dir + "\download\downloaded.mkv") Then
                    Else
                        ProgressBar1.Value = 45
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If FileExists(dir + "\download\dvid.mp4") Then
                If FileExists(dir + "\download\dvid.mp4.part") Then
                Else
                    ProgressBar1.Value = 45
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop
```

when ever I get my application up a run this code the app stops responding so am I doing something wrong or is there something missing?

Comment: Don't use a loop at all.  Use a `FileSystemWatcher` to receive notifications of changes to the file system.

Comment: how would I use file system watcher? and how does it work?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the information you found when you searched the web and MSDN in particular?

Comment: I hardly know anything about the vb coding language, just started learning to code in it to day and so far have gotten lucky when putting my code together this is the first major problem I've had :/ and had no luck with google

Comment: You don't need luck when using Google. You just need to use the appropriate keywords. If you want to find information about using the `FileSystemWatcher` class in VB.NET then search for "filesystemwatcher vb.net". Skill trumps luck every day, so just search for the appropriate topic and you'll find appropriate information.

Comment: I finally found a fix since I was starting something to  write those files from the app I was making I figured a way to just wait for the process to exit then continue my code but thx for your help

Comment: If you have answered your own question then you should post it as an answer and accept it.  That way, people will see that the question has been answered and not waste their time opening it with the intention of providing an answer.  You answer may also help someone else.  There's also a chance that we may see an issue with your solution and provide an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

using wait for exit on process fixed my problem

```
Dim p As New Process
        Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(dir + "file to start.exe")
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        psi.Arguments = "-x --audio-format mp3 --output /downloaded/downloaded.mkv " + Form1.TextBox1.Text
        p.StartInfo = psi
        p.Start()
        p.WaitForExit()
```